# Handling NotFound response from Web API

Tags: asp.net, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

One of my ASP.NET Web API project has such code:

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetStatusById(int sid)
{
    try
    {
        var mds = TheRepository.GetStatusById(sid);
        if (mds != null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, TheModelFactory.Create(mds));
        }
        else
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
    }
}
```

In the same solution, but in another project I'm coding client (ASP.Net Website), which will read and write data through this WebAPI.

At first client should check if record already exists in database:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = "id,description")] MDS mds)
{
    if (mds == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "No data given to server");
    }
    else
    {
        MDS reqMds = await _mdApiService.GetMDS ByStatus(Convert.ToInt32(mds.Id));                    

        if (reqMds == null )
        {
            await _mdApiService.CreateMDS(mds);
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, "Already exists");
        }
    }
    return View("Details", mds);
}
```

When I call this method, I get NotFound-Page in my browser instead of getting Response to Client (website) and parsing it.
The goal is to show error from WebSite Project, not from Web API project.

What is the right way to check on client that record already exists through Web API?

Comment: Your question is unclear because the Web API method at the top is not being called by the action method at the bottom. Regardless, applications are not aware of "projects" and "solutions". If you have 2 projects, you have 2 separate applications and they will act like separate applications. If you want to share behavior, put them into the same project or a class library that is shared between the projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to edit my server Web API to check for duplicate entry. On the client only transmitting actions from user to API.